# *ngIf is not working in my Html but ngIf showing first content

Tags: angular, angular-ng-if, angular10

I had seen a lot of questions regarding this problem. but them not helped for me.

Here the my Html

```
 <div class="pl-lg-4">
          <div *ngIf="isStorySelected; else hi" class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-12">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Story Name</label>
                &nbsp; &nbsp;<label class="form-control-label" for="input-username">Selected option</label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <ng-template #hi>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label class="form-control-label">Select Story</label>
                  <select class="form-control form-control-alternative" value="">
                    <option>some option one</option>
                    <option>some option 2</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </ng-template>
```

if I used *ngIf like this it's shows nothing. but using like ngIf shows first content.

Here the my component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Route } from '@angular/compiler/src/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-create-episodes',
  templateUrl: './create-episodes.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-episodes.component.scss']
})
export class CreateEpisodesComponent implements OnInit {

  public activeRoutes: ActivatedRoute;
  public storyId: string;
  public isStorySelected = false;

  constructor(activeRoutes: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.activeRoutes = activeRoutes;

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.storyId = this.activeRoutes.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    if (this.storyId) {
      console.log('1');
      this.isStorySelected = true;
    } else {
      console.log('2');
      this.isStorySelected = false;
    }
  }
}
```

here I added the stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmxswk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

I already imported the CommonModule to the appModule.

And Im using the latest version of Angular. (10)

Comment: Did you put isStorySelected on screen to display its current value? Now you are using it only to control if condition. You need to display value of it after you be sure about your code.

Comment: can you create stackblitz demo for this

Comment: @PalakJadav sure.

Comment: @LuDeveloper I didn't get what you mean?

Comment: here the https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lmxswk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the interface of [ActivatedRoute](https://angular.io/api/router/ActivatedRoute)

`paramMap` return `Observable<ParamMap>`, Hence you need to convert it to observable

```
name = 'Angular';
public storyId: Observable<boolean>;
public router: ActivatedRoute;

constructor(router: ActivatedRoute) {
  this.router = router;
}

ngOnInit(){
    this.storyId = this.router.paramMap.pipe(
      map((res) =>{
        const currentId = res.get('id');
        if(currentId){
          return  true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
    }));
  }
```

Inside template

```
<div *ngIf="storyId | async; else hi" class="row"></div>
```

Here is working [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-abd4rt?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

Hope this will resolve your problem. missing `then` option cause the problem.

```
<div *ngIf="isStorySelected; then hello; else hi" class="row">
   <ng-template #hello>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
   </ng-template>
   <ng-template #hi>
      <h1>Hi</h1>
   </ng-template>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check is the value of `storyId` after initialization? Feels like the app router cause the problem....